# How to convert object to map in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

using Stream I get the data from firebase

```
void getsds() async {
DatabaseReference ref =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("NearbyAccidents/User1/acc_coordinates");



Stream<DatabaseEvent> stream = ref.onValue;



stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
  print('Event Type: ${event.type}'); // DatabaseEventType.value;

  print('Snapshot: ${event.snapshot.value}');

  List<Object?> map1 = event.snapshot.value as dynamic;

  print(map1[0]);

});
```

}

[image]

for printing map[0]
I got this. but this is object. so I want to convert as map

How can covert this object to map

Comment: i think this is of type map can you check it using map[0].runtimeType

Comment: _InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>.           it shows like this . when I print (map1[0]['lat']).         The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Answer (score 2):

```
final mapCreated = Map.from(map1[0] as Map<Object?, Object?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will solve your problem

```
final mapCreated = Map.from(map1[0]);
```

Comment: I got this 
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Comment: Map.from(map1[0]  as Map<String, dynamic>)   try this

Comment: did it solved your problem?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: did you solved it?

Comment: I solved like final mapCreated = Map.from(map1[0] as Map<Object?, Object?>);  by the way Thankyou